# Merging multiple ACCESS files in R

Tags: r

I am trying to merge different ACCESS files (located in different subfolders under the same folder). After reading through different blogs and some of the questions people have asked here, I came up with the code below.

```
Parent.Folder<-"D:/Documents/Rwd"
setwd(Parent.Folder)
library(RODBC)
subfolders<-list.dirs(Parent.Folder, recursive = TRUE)[-1]
list_filenames<-list.files(subfolders, recursive = FALSE)
list_filenames<-paste("D:/Documents/Rwd/", list_filenames, sep="")
list_filenames<-sub(".mdb","",list_filenames)
for (file in list_filenames){
  if(!exists("data")){
    channel<-odbcConnectAccess(file)
    data<-sqlQuery(channel,paste("select* from HRESULTS"))
    close(channel)  
    }

  if(exists("data")){
    channel<-odbcConnectAccess(file)
    temp_data<-sqlQuery(channel,paste("select* from HRESULTS"))
    data<-rbind(data,temp_data)
    rm(temp_data)
    close(channel)  
  }
}
```

All tables are in the same format and my aim is to get them in one data frame. The first if statement ran fine and gave me a data frame with data from first file but after that I am getting the error "Error in sqlQuery(channel, paste("select* from HRESULTS")) : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel"
I have never worked with ODBC or SQL before so my apologies if I am making a very obvious mistake. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your error is the file existing. Access files are finicky they like to be connected via R-32 bit for one. Also depending on the file, `odbcConnectAccess2007`may serve you better. Notably my experience is with .accdb files, not sure if they act differently. Side note, your queries look fine, you can use `sqlFetch` if you are grabbing a whole table, it's a bit faster I've found.

Comment: [This](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Hmisc/html/mdb.get.html) may also help, it just pulls the mdb table in from the package `Hmisc`.

Comment: @Badger - I tried installing mdb-tools package because it looks like that is necessary for Hmisc but got an error that 'mdb-tools' is not avaialble for R version 3.2.3. Not sure what should be done to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a file-level database system like SQLite, MS Access files require full path references including extensions in ODBC connections.

For your needs, consider using the [list.files](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/list.files) argument `full.names = TRUE` and then filter the list for only viable access extensions, .mdb or .accdb. Finally, consider using lapply for a growing list of imported query data tables that you can later run a `do.call(rbind...)` to concatenate to final dataframe:

```
Parent.Folder <- "D:/Documents/Rwd"
subfolders <- list.dirs(Parent.Folder, recursive = TRUE)[-1]

list_filenames <- list.files(subfolders, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
acc_files <- list_filenames[grep(".mdb|.accdb", list_filenames)]

output <- lapply(acc_files, 
                 function(file) {
                    channel <- odbcConnectAccess(file) 
                    # ALTERNATIVE CONNECTION
                    # channel <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0('driver=
                    #            {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
                    #            DBQ=', file))                        
                    data <- sqlQuery(channel, "select * from HRESULTS")
                    close(channel)
                    return(data) 
                })

data <- do.call(rbind, output)
```

Comment: @ Parfait- I can't thank you enough. The script ran without any errors. I am not sure what I was doing wrong. Would it be possible for you to explain the issues with my script. If not, I understand. Thank you again!

Comment: If I'm understanding it's because you subbed out the .mdb (file extension) as per the blogs, however the system required the full name with extension in order to connect to the database!

Comment: Correct @Badger. OP removed the extension and if sub-sub directories were included may have pasted the incorrect path for some files. So simply use `full.names`. Further, non-mdb files would be passed into odbc connection.